# How do I use the Rails toggle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to be able to use [toggle](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle) but not quite sure how to do this.

I have a boolean attribute called `deceased` on my `Member` model.

Yet when I try to toggle it with `toggle(attribute)` it doesn't work.

This is what happens at the command-line:

```
[41] pry(main)> member.deceased.toggle!
NoMethodError: undefined method `toggle!' for true:TrueClass
from (pry):41:in `__pry__'
[42] pry(main)> member.toggle(deceased)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `deceased' for main:Object
from (pry):42:in `__pry__'
[43] pry(main)> member.deceased.toggle
NoMethodError: undefined method `toggle' for true:TrueClass
from (pry):43:in `__pry__'
[44] pry(main)> member.deceased
=> true
[45] pry(main)> toggle(member.deceased)
NoMethodError: undefined method `toggle' for main:Object
from (pry):45:in `__pry__'
```

How do I use `toggle`?

FYI: All of the above was done at the `rails c`...but I have pry installed. But given that `toggle` seems to be an ActiveRecord method, it shouldn't be an issue right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it with

```
member.toggle(:deceased)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks much!

Comment: additional bang method: member.toggle!(:deceased)